# How can I load content from two different folders (based on the subdomain) and keep the old URLs?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

My website is `example.com`.

In my public_html folder, I have two folders. One is called `main`, and the other is called `report`.

When somebody navigates to `example.com`, I want to serve content from the `main` folder, but I want their URL to remain the same.

So, if they navigate to `example.com/file.html`, I want them to see the `file.html` file that's in the `main` folder, but I **don't** want their URL to change to `example.com/main/file.html`.

Similarly, if they navigate to `report.example.com/report1.pdf`, I want them to see the `report1.pdf` file that's in the `report` folder, but I **don't** want their URL to change to `report.example.com/report/report1.pdf`.

The closest thing I've been able to achieve is this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!main).*)$ /main/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^report.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!report).*)$ /report/$1 [L]
```

That seems to work to some extent, but:

- If somebody navigates to `http://example.com/report/index.html`, the server incorrectly loads the `index.html` file from the `public_html/report` folder rather than the `public_html/main/report` folder. Normally that path would make sense, but in this case I'm trying to change that behavior.
- If somebody navigates to `http://report.example.com/test`, the server correctly displays the `public_html/test/index.html` file, but redirects them to `http://report.example.com/report/test/`.

How can I load the correct files and keep the URLs correct?

Comment: Do you have access to apache configuration files, or `.htaccess` is the only option?

Comment: @DusanBajic - We're using Cloudways, so we have some options but not total control.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^ /main%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^reports.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^ /reports%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```